# SQL returns 2 of the 3 rows

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to select something from a table and insert that information into another table
For example I've 3 rows in table A which I want to insert into table B, he only inserts 2 of the 3.

I got this: I've tried it with fetch_array() but I get only the error non-object

EDIT: THE PART OF THE SCRIPT

```
    $log = $db->query("SELECT itemname FROM log_mitem WHERE mobname = '".$mobname."' AND game = '".$game."'") or die($db->error);
    if($log1 = $log->fetch_object());
    {
        while($loco = $log->fetch_object())
    {
```

Comment: i'm guessing it's not adding the first object?

Comment: Im not 100% sure, but I think its because you are using grab object 2x. try and use it only once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't have that first if, just do:

```
$log = $db->query("SELECT itemname FROM log_mitem WHERE mobname = '".$mobname."' AND game = '".$game."'") or die($db->error);
while($loco = $log->fetch_object()) {
 // do something
}
```

Also note that you don't need a while loop for this trivial task, you can use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` syntax

```
INSERT INTO table1 ( column1 )
SELECT  col1
FROM    table2  
WHERE   cond1
```

Comment: I've editted my OP thread, because after select I need to insert somehting

Comment: Wow, i feel realy dumb atm! Thank you it works! I just tried this for hours... Learned something new! thank you